# Why won't this getJSON work?

Tags: html, json, syntax

I'm new to web programming and have been bashing my head against the wall for hours on end.

I've tried putting a `var city = document.getElementById("cityname").value;` inside of the setCityName() function and simply used that, but unfortunately, that gives me "null" for the city, even if I pass something in the textbox.

I'm hoping someone can see my mistake(s) and teach me something about getJSON and web programming in general. Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>img{ height: 100px; float: left; }</style>
</head>
<body>
      <form>
City name: <input type="text" id="cityname" name="city" value=""><br />
Latitude: <input type="text" id="latitude" name="lat" value=""><br />
<input id="Subb" type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="ttest()">
</form>

<script>

var a;
function ttest()
{
    a = document.getElementById("cityname").value;
    setCityName(a);
}

function setCityName(a)
{   
    var cityURL = "http://api.geonames.org/postalCodeSearchJSON?placename="+a+"&maxRows=10&username=demo";
    $.getJSON( cityURL, function(data) {alert("Hi");})
        .success(function() {alert("testSuccess");})
        .fail(function() {alert("testFail");});
}


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What error do you get when you try the code? "web programming in general." it's too broad and you are not describing your problem good enough. What are you trying to achieve with this specific problem?

Comment: Hi Victor; in short form, I'm trying to have a user type in a city name in the textbox formed by the input HTML tag. From there, the user hits the Submit box and a Javascript function will be called to call a JSON web service to look up postal code(s) for the city entered. In long form, my problem is that whenever I add in the "getJSON" portion of my setCityName function, I run into lots of trouble. I'm running out of space, but I'm starting to think it could be my particular browser or setup; I'm on Ubuntu, and it seems to be working fine on my Windows setup. I'll keep hacking at it.

Comment: "I run into lots of trouble" is still not specific enough but try looking at the answer given by Racso if you have problem with running the code. "I'm running out of space" definitely sounds like something else than the code. Sounds strange to come from a json request.

Answer (score 1):

I've tested your code (with some minor changes in order to make it work in jsFiddle) and it works correctly.

Javascript:

```
var a;

function ttest() {
    a = document.getElementById("cityname").value;
    setCityName(a);
}

function setCityName(a) {
    var cityURL = "http://api.geonames.org/postalCodeSearchJSON?placename=" + a + "&maxRows=10&username=demo";
    console.log(cityURL);
    var city = document.getElementById("cityname").value;
    console.log(city);
    $.getJSON(cityURL, function (data) {
        console.log("Hi");
    })
        .success(function (data) {
        console.log("testSuccess");
        console.log(data)
    })
        .fail(function () {
        console.log("testFail");
    });
}
```

[Check it out live here](http://jsfiddle.net/N6Rg2/1/).

Suggestion: don't use the same name (`a`) for both a global variable and a function parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Well according to this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HFKnC/ it works! but you're using a GET request and the api wants a POST request. So take

```
$.post();
```

instead of

```
$.getJSON();
```